# How do I use multi line scripts in selenium to execute a script

Tags: python, selenium

I am deploying some JavaScript on a page with selenium's driver.execute_script function.

I prepare my JavaScript but if I drop the code into another line like so:

```
script = 'line one code' +
         'line two code'
driver.execute_script(script)
```

It gives me an error.
I've also tried doing:

```
script = [
    'line one code',
    'line two code'
]
script = ';'.join(script)
```

But that gave me same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To construct a multi-line script, you can take help of the *triple quotes* i.e. **`""" ... """`**.

Here is a example of multi-line script which is invoked through `execute_script()` using *Selenium*:

```
def wheel_element(element, deltaY = 120, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0):
  error = element._parent.execute_script("""
    var element = arguments[0];
    var deltaY = arguments[1];
    var box = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var clientX = box.left + (arguments[2] || box.width / 2);
    var clientY = box.top + (arguments[3] || box.height / 2);
    var target = element.ownerDocument.elementFromPoint(clientX, clientY);

    for (var e = target; e; e = e.parentElement) {
      if (e === element) {
        target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover', {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, clientX: clientX, clientY: clientY}));
        target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousemove', {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, clientX: clientX, clientY: clientY}));
        target.dispatchEvent(new WheelEvent('wheel',     {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, clientX: clientX, clientY: clientY, deltaY: deltaY}));
        return;
      }
    }    
    return "Element is not interactable";
    """, element, deltaY, offsetX, offsetY)
```

You can call the method as:

```
wheel_element(elm, -120)
```

Comment: In the case of executing the Script for driver.execute_script(), is it different? I see you are doing it into an element

Answer (score 0):

Add `\` after the `+` sign

```
script = 'line one code ' + \
         'line two code'
```

Or use round brackets

```
script = ('line one code '
          'line two code')
```